# Why is ROC analysis not used in optimization problems?

Tags: optimization

In machine learning and applied fields of statistics, receiver operating characterization (ROC) analysis is commonly used to select optimal algorithms/models. However, at a lecture I once attended on mathematical optimization, I remember the lecturer saying that ROC analysis just wasn't considered a useful approach to optimization. No justification was offered. As a non-mathematician, I want to know (1) is this true that ROC analysis is not used in optimization problems and (2) if so, why?

Answer (score 2):

The lecturer was wrong.  It is now an [active area of research](https://www.google.com/search?q=roc%20optimization%20nips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=roc%20optimization%20auc&oq=roc%20optimization%20auc&gs_l=serp.3...14065.16450.1.17630.6.5.1.0.0.0.147.635.0j5.5.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.J72BV3u7wb0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=36ad7c0967172426&bpcl=39650382&biw=1280&bih=643) (though outside my speciality). For instance, in [a paper at NIPS](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_AA40.pdf) in 2003, they discuss using ROC AUC instead of error as an objective function in training neural networks.